# Hide downloaded files in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, download, save

I am making a flutter app where i have to download files from the a distant server.

but I want to make those files only accessible from my app, and not from other file managers or other apps like Netflix does with their app.

how can I achieve that in flutter?

thank you in advance.

Comment: welcome ....add you trial code and error snippet ..you did not get ready made code . stack if for query and error resolving purpose not for ready made code ...so please refer How to ask question  section first .

Comment: hi @AjayMistry, i am not looking for ready made code. My question is about where should i look .. because i didn't find anything pointing to where i can store files .. beside the local storage .. which will be available to the user, And that is what I asked the question

Comment: @ayoubmoussaid did you find the solution for this query? I am having a same query, but didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package.

```
final Directory appDocumentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

This file location is a private storage directory of an application

Answer (score 0):

you can use [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

> A CacheManager to download and cache files in the cache directory of the app. Various settings on how long to keep a file can be changed.

> It uses the cache-control http header to efficiently retrieve files.

example

```
 var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
```

> How it works

By default the cached files are stored in the temporary directory of the app. This means the OS can delete the files any time.

Information about the files is stored in a database using sqflite. The file name of the database is the key of the cacheManager, that's why that has to be unique.

This cache information contains the end date till when the file is valid and the eTag to use with the http cache-control.